# Poor internet on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: networking, 21.04, iwlwifi

I am getting about 500Mb/s on my MacBook Air which I am on right now, however, on my Ubuntu desktop, the internet speed is around 1Mb/s, and it keeps dropping in and out. I am using the iwlwifi drivers on Ubuntu 21.04. What other commands should I run to get you information that you need. Thanks! In addition, it is extremely unreliable, cutting in and out every 30 seconds or so.

Here is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlp7s0
       version: 1a
       serial: a4:b1:c1:09:84:b8
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.11.0-16-generic firmware=59.601f3a66.0 cc-a0-59.ucode ip=192.168.1.48 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:24 memory:fc500000-fc503fff
```

Here is the output of `cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

options iwlwifi disable_11ax=Y
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8
options iwlwifi power_save=0
options iwlmvm power_scheme=1
options iwlwifi d0i3_disable=1
options iwlwifi uapsd_disable=1
```

I tried uncommenting `precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100` in `/etc/gai.conf`

Here is the output of `ip l | grep $(ip r | awk '/default/ {print $5}' ) | awk '{print $2, $4, $5}'`

```
enx9a60ca44ea50: mtu 1500
```

Comment: What's your MTU? `ip l | grep $(ip r | awk '/default/ {print $5}' ) | awk '{print $2, $4, $5}'`. Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: I updated my post